# ¿Cómo pasar información de una tabla a un modal?

Tags: php, bootstrap, modal

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: tengo una tabla con la siguiente información

```
  <table name="label"  id="table"  class="tables   table-hover table-sm table-striped table-bordered  " >
 <a text-align="left" class="text-center">Etiqueta de compras</a>
 <br>  <br>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th class="H5" hidden>ID</th>
      <th class="H5">No. Factura</th>
      <th class="H5" >Fec. recepcion</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Codigo</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Descripción</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Lote</th>
      <th class="H5">Proveedor</th>
      <th class="H5" >Usuario</th>
      <th class="H5" >Cantidad</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>U.M</th>
      <th>✔</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listEmployees">

      <?php include_once 'employee.list.php';
      ?>

    </tbody>

  </table>

  <?php
        //incluimos el fichero de conexion
        include_once('database.class.php');

        $database = new Connection();
        $db = $database->open();
        try{
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vw_etiqueta_cp';
            foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                ?>
                
<tr>

<td hidden><?=$row['id'] ?></td>
<td  ><?=$row['invoice'] ?></td>
<td ><?= $row['date_received'] ?></td>
<td hidden><?= $row['key'] ?></td>
<td  hidden><?= $row['description'] ?></td>
<td  hidden><?= $row['lote'] ?></td>
<td  ><?= $row['business_name'] ?></td>
<td  ><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
<td  ><?= $row['amount_received'] ?></td>
<td  hidden><?= $row['prefix'] ?></td>
 <td><a type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-dark"   data-toggle="modal" href="#labelModal" >Generar Etiqueta</a></td>

  </td>
</tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Necesito pasar esta información a un modal con un botón para imprimir en un formato de etiqueta que ya tengo diseñado pero no encuentro la manera de pasar la info de la tabla , que se lleve la fila seleccionada la información al modal

de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda

Este es el codigo con el que estoy jalando al informacion de la fila al boton con une evento onclick

```
onclick="selCompra(\''+invoice+'\',\''+data_received+'\',\''+key+'\',\''+description+'\',\''+lote+\',\''+business_name+\',\''+name+\',\''+amount_received+\',\''+prefix+\');"
```

y esta la funcion

```
selCompra = function(invoice, data_received, key, description, lote, business_name, name, amount_received, prefix){ $('invoice').val(invoice); $('data_received').val(data_received); $('key').val(key); $('description').val(description); $('lote').val(lote); $('business_name').val(business_name); $('name').val(name); $('amount_received').val(amount_received); $('prefix').val(prefix); };
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: @JheymanMejia intenté llevarme la información de la fila con el evento onclick en el boton  

onclick="selCompra(\''+invoice+'\',\''+data_received+'\',\''+key+'\',\''+description+'\',\''+lote+\',\''+business_name+\',\''+name+\',\''+amount_received+\',\''+prefix+\');"

con la siguiente función:

Comment: selCompra = function(invoice, data_received, key, description, lote, business_name, name, amount_received, prefix){

$('invoice').val(invoice);
$('data_received').val(data_received);
$('key').val(key);
$('description').val(description);
$('lote').val(lote);
$('business_name').val(business_name);
$('name').val(name);
$('amount_received').val(amount_received);
$('prefix').val(prefix);

};

Comment: el problema es que no es de una tabla a un formulario, si no de una tabla a otra tabla dentro del modal

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] para agregar el código que indicás en los comentarios _en la pregunta_. Desde los comentarios se dificulta la lectura.

Comment: @padaleiana listo

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de asignar evento en línea `onclick="..."` hazlo por medio de los eventos de jQuery. Lee los comentarios en código y los enlaces al final de la respuesta para saber qué hace cada cosa.

Por cierto, el enlace dentro de la tabla hace que el HTML sea incorrecto, o lo pones fuera de la tabla o creas una fila y celda para colocarlo dentro.

```js
// La función se mantiene, pero se ejecuta desde el evento
const selCompra = function(invoice, data_received, key, description, lote, business_name, name, amount_received, prefix) {
    console.log(invoice, data_received, key, description, lote, business_name, name, amount_received, prefix);
    /* Descomenta este bloque para asignar valores
    $('invoice').val(invoice);
    $('data_received').val(data_received);
    $('key').val(key);
    $('description').val(description);
    $('lote').val(lote);
    $('business_name').val(business_name);
    $('name').val(name);
    $('amount_received').val(amount_received);
    $('prefix').val(prefix);
    */
};

// Asignar evento a enlaces por contenedor y clase
$('#table .btn-outline-dark').on('click', function(e) {
    // Es un enlace, se recomienda cancelar comportamiento por defecto
    e.preventDefault();
    // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el enlace
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // Obtener celdas de esta fila
    let tds = $(tr).children('td');
    // Ejecutar función
    selCompra(
        // Primera celda (0) contiene ID, seguramente la necesitarás
        // Segunda celda (1) Número de factura, .text() obtiene contenido
        $(tds).eq(1).text(), // invoice,
        $(tds).eq(2).text(), // data_received,
        $(tds).eq(3).text(), // key,
        $(tds).eq(4).text(), // description,
        $(tds).eq(5).text(), // lote,
        $(tds).eq(6).text(), // business_name,
        $(tds).eq(7).text(), // name,
        $(tds).eq(8).text(), // amount_received,
        $(tds).eq(9).text(), // prefix
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Este enlace debe quedar fuera de la tabla -->
<p><a text-align="left" class="text-center">Etiqueta de compras</a></p>
<table name="label"  id="table"  class="tables   table-hover table-sm table-striped table-bordered  " >
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th class="H5" hidden>ID</th>
      <th class="H5">No. Factura</th>
      <th class="H5" >Fec. recepcion</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Codigo</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Descripción</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>Lote</th>
      <th class="H5">Proveedor</th>
      <th class="H5" >Usuario</th>
      <th class="H5" >Cantidad</th>
      <th class="H5" hidden>U.M</th>
      <th>✔</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listEmployees">
        <tr>
            <td hidden>1</td>
            <td>Inoice 1</td>
            <td>Fecha 1</td>
            <td hidden>Key 1</td>
            <td hidden>Descripción 1</td>
            <td hidden>Lote 1</td>
            <td>Nombre de negocio 1</td>
            <td>Nombre 1</td>
            <td>Importe 1</td>
            <td hidden>Prefijo 1</td>
            <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" href="#labelModal" >Generar Etiqueta</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td hidden>2</td>
            <td>Inoice 2</td>
            <td>Fecha 2</td>
            <td hidden>Key 2</td>
            <td hidden>Descripción 2</td>
            <td hidden>Lote 2</td>
            <td>Nombre de negocio 2</td>
            <td>Nombre 2</td>
            <td>Importe 2</td>
            <td hidden>Prefijo 2</td>
            <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" href="#labelModal" >Generar Etiqueta</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

- [$.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) - Asignar eventos
- [$.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - Obtener padre con selector específico
- [$.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) - Obtener hijos de un elemento
- [$.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) - Acceder a un elemento por posición (o índice)
- [$.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) - Obtener contenido del elemento